# Setting up ingress in the minikube not working

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube

According to [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) on the Kubernetes official website, I want to set hostnames for my services in the local cluster (I have implemented a `hello world` example like documentation exactly).

I've written these commands after starting pure minikube:

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
$ k get pods -n ingress-nginx

NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-5pthd        0/1     Completed   0          137m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-h9vrh         0/1     Completed   1          137m
ingress-nginx-controller-56cf58c77c-9rnr6   1/1     Running     0          137m
```

```
$ k create ns hello
$ k create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 -n hello
$ k expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080 -n hello
$ k get service web -n hello

NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web    NodePort   10.96.235.52   <none>        8080:30282/TCP   61s
```

```
$ k apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml -n hello
$ k get ingress -n hello

NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   hello-world.info             80      35s
```

My minikube IP is `192.168.49.2`, so I added the below line to the end of my `/etc/hosts`.

```
192.168.49.2 hello-world.info
```

But, I can't see anything in the browser. I don't have any problem with `minikube service web -n hello` or Kubernetes port forward. It seems there is a problem with my ingress.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a [known issue with minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues), Ingress works properly on linux only. After the addon is enabled, please run **"minikube tunnel"** and your ingress resources would be available at `“192.168.49.2”`.

So, in this scenario when using Minikube on Windows/MacOS you are actually supposed to use a  [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/). Bear in mind that Minikube is mainly used for testing and learning purposes so some of its features might not be ideal.

Comment: This example ran on the `ubuntu 22.04`. And unfortunately `minikube tunnel` didn't help.

Comment: @MohammadrezaKhedri, The deployment which you are using doesn't have an external IP for which you are not able to view it in your external browser. Also Can you let me know where you performed this task whether on the local machine or in a virtual machine

Comment: @MohammadrezaKhedri, Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.